# Sharing error: mount error(2): No such file or directory Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)

Tags: mount, samba, fstab, cifs

I need to share some folder via typical adsl home modem by [this instruction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lI-HwfRZqqs):

[image]

so i tried this codes :

[image]

```
so@so-notebook:~$ sudo aptitude install cifs-utils -y
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cifs-utils 
0 packages upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 71.5 kB of archives. After unpacking 231 kB will be used.
Get: 1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 cifs-utils amd64 2:6.8-1 [71.5 kB]
Fetched 71.5 kB in 2s (44.0 kB/s)     
Selecting previously unselected package cifs-utils.
(Reading database ... 333471 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../cifs-utils_2%3a6.8-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking cifs-utils (2:6.8-1) ...
Setting up cifs-utils (2:6.8-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/cifs-utils/idmapwb.so to provide /etc/cifs-utils/idmap-plugin (idmap-plugin) in auto mode
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
```

so inside my Vmware virtual machine installed win8 and tried to share one folder with New_folder name like this :

and get this error:

```
so@so-notebook:~/Desktop/trash$ sudo mount.cifs -o username=Guest //172.16.144.130//WIN-KBJV8JRF8FS/New_folder /home/so/Desktop/trash/ip_shar_test
Password for Guest@//172.16.144.130//WIN-KBJV8JRF8FS/New_folder:  
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
so@so-notebook:~/Desktop/trash$ sudo mount.cifs -o username=Guest //172.16.144.130/Guest /home/so/Desktop/trash/ip_shar_test
Password for Guest@//172.16.144.130/Guest:  
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
so@so-notebook:~/Desktop/trash$ sudo mount.cifs -o username=Guest //172.16.144.130/Guest /home/so/Desktop/trash/ip_shar_test
Password for Guest@//172.16.144.130/Guest:  
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
so@so-notebook:~/Desktop/trash$ sudo mount.cifs -o username=Guest //172.16.144.130/Guest /WIN-KBJV8JRF8FS/New_folder
Couldn't chdir to /WIN-KBJV8JRF8FS/New_folder: No such file or directory
so@so-notebook:~/Desktop/trash$ sudo mount.cifs -o username=Guest //172.16.144.130/Guest /home/so/Desktop/trash/ip_shar_test
Password for Guest@//172.16.144.130/Guest:  
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
so@so-notebook:~/Desktop/trash$ sudo mount.cifs -o username=Guest //172.16.144.130//WIN-KBJV8JRF8FS/New_folder /home/so/Desktop/trash/ip_shar_test
Password for Guest@//172.16.144.130//WIN-KBJV8JRF8FS/New_folder:  
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
so@so-notebook:~/Desktop/trash$ sudo mount.cifs -o username=Guest //172.16.144.130/Guest/New* /home/so/Desktop/trash/ip_shar_test
Password for Guest@//172.16.144.130/Guest/New*:  
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
so@so-notebook:~/Desktop/trash$ sudo mount.cifs -o username=Guest //172.16.144.130/Guest /home/so/Desktop/trash/ip_shar_test
Password for Guest@//172.16.144.130/Guest:  
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

SO what do you think?

Thanks for your attention.

Comment: What does `smbclient -L 172.16.144.130` show?